# Update picklist value based on formula field

Tags: workflow, picklist, formula-field

I have a picklist field which has value Yes and No. I would like to know if I can update this picklist field value based on a formula field.

The `formula field calculates` whether the value will be yes or no.

Comment: Instead of creating a separate formula field, can't you use the same formula in a workflow (field update) to update the picklist field value?

Comment: I can , but I would have to create a new workflow rule. I have limited workflow rules left for my org, so trying to find a work around.

Comment: What about putting the logic in Apex?

Comment: From what you are saying I guess picklist can not be updated using a formula field. I was wondering to make the picklist as text type and update the value based on a formula. Doing this I would have changed the picklist to text field type.

Comment: As far as I know, updating a field of any type can be done through Apex, Workflow field update and Visual workflow/Process Builder. Without these, you have to make it a formula field.

Comment: Can't you just replace the picklist field w the formula field,  I mean why do you need it to be a picklist, since its just set by the formula. How about a text formula that outputs "yes" or "no"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Workflow Field Update to set a picklist value requires a unique workflow for each possible picklist value to set.

However, you can use ProcessBuilder to set picklist fields via a formula. This was delivered in Summer 15.  Here is an example where Field `some picklist` has two possible values - `Choice00` and `Choice01`. Using the value of `some_currency_fld__c`, the picklist is set dynamically

[image]